# Suppress unidentified property warning when using magic __get method

Tags: php, class, codeigniter, warnings

I've got a CI Library which loads translatable content from an XML file into a class, and the class has a magic __get method which checks if that property is defined when it is referenced, returning the localised key if so, or the keyname plus '_#' to let me know that translation is missing if not.

All cool.

However, because this all depends on properties on an object, I get lots of 'notice: undefined etc..' warnings when I'm running in debug (E_ALL), and it's annoying. I don't want to disable notices, but i do want to know how to disable this inside this particular library (if possible). I could put @ in front of every call to the class, but again, that's pretty horrible too.

Any tips?

Simplified code snippets below:

```
class MY_Translation
{

    function _get_keys($lang) {
        // load xml translations, could split this into different files..

        $translations = new DOMDocument();
        $translations->load($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/xml/translations.xml");
        if ($translations) {
            $words = $translations->getElementsByTagName("word");
            $count = 0;
            foreach( $words as $word ){

                $name = $word->getAttribute('name');
                $trans = $word->childNodes;

                if ($trans->length > 0) {
                    for($i = 0; $i < $trans->length; $i++) {
                        $child = $trans->item($i); 

                        if ($child->nodeName == $lang) {
                            $this->$name = $child->nodeValue;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }   
        }
    }

    function __get($key){
        if (property_exists('MY_Translation',$this->$key)) {
            return $this->$key;
        } else {
            return $key."_#";
        }
    }

}
```

XML (just for reference, so it's clear what's happening):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<words>
    <word name="thing">
        <en>thing en</en>
        <pt>thing pt</pt>
    </word>
</words>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you use `$this` to store the translations, `__get` is only called on non-existent properties. Change it, the warning you get only notifies you that you're doing something wrong:

```
function __get($key)
{
    return $key."_#";
}
```

That's really all you need to do.

---

Did you mean

```
$this->t->$key
```

instead of

```
$this->$key
```

?

Then you would need to fix the assignment as well:

```
$this->t->$name = ...
```

In general, as you check for the property in the `__get` function you should not see any warning. The warnings show you that you've made some error in your program logic, so they are useful and you should not disable them not even for a short part of your code. Disabling warnings is not the solution but fixing the code.

Let me know if this was helpful.

Comment: Sorry, I left that t = new stdClass in by mistake. But, you helped me focus on where the warning was being triggered - on the 'property_exists' not on the __get, nor the reference which initiates that call. Putting @ in front of property_exists suppressed the warning.

Comment: Putting @ to supress errors is a bad practice. You should avoid using it.

Comment: If you refer to `$this` to store the translations as properties, `__get` will only be called if it does not exists. So you don't even need to check for it. Instead just return the string that it won't exist. As written, you should fix the error, not suppress it.

Comment: @danp: I edited the answer and added you the function like you should need it.

Comment: Does a warning trigger an exception? If I handled the exception, would it still trigger a display notice?

Comment: @Danp: By default configuration, warnings do not trigger an exception. But you're looking at the wrong place. Fix the code, the warnings help you to locate errors as you already noticed in your question. That's the right direction. Stick to it ;)